# Unity Ads Mediation option missing from dashboard?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads, unityads

I would like to use Unity Ads Mediation for a new project.
It is set up successfuly on the editor, however on the project dashboard in the monetization settings, under mediation, I can only see these options. Isn't it possible to use Unity Ads Mediation anymore?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unity Mediation is merged with IronSource.

> [Unity and ironSource’s new partnership](https://unity.com/unity-ads-ironsource)

According to the FAQ about your new project:

> Unity LevelPlay is the recommended mediation solution from Unity.
> While Unity Mediation is still accessible via technical documentation
> and the Unity editor, it will no longer be enhanced and will
> eventually be removed.

Comment: Yes, that is clear, the recommended way is LevelPlay, but it shouldn't mean that out of the sudden Unity Ads Mediation is discarded, right?

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @LoïcLeGrosFrère is complete.

Extra info from the page https://unity.com/unity-ads-ironsource
[image: Source]